# Cross-Origin-Resource-Sharing isn't permitted in my Heroku Express API

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

I have a front-end client hosted at  'https://project-front.herokuapp.com'. it makes calls to an api hosted at 'https://project-api.herokuapp.com/ (these aren't the actual URLs). 
Whenever I make an api call, I get

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://project-api.herokuapp.com/login' from origin 'https://project-front.herokuapp.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'https://project-api.herokuapp.com/' that is not equal to the supplied origin.
```

and

```
Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://appli-api.herokuapp.com/login with MIME type application/json. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.
```

Clearly, this is a CORS issue. My server.js has

```
app.use(cors())

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", '*');
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", 'Origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,content-type,application/json');
  next();
});
```

and each of the router files containing my routes files also has

```
// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
router.use(bodyParser.json()); // support json encoded bodies
router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // support encoded bodies
```

It should also be noted that my .gitignore includes `node_modules` in order for the bcrypt to work on heroku. How can I get my CORS to pass?

Comment: do not use app.use(cors())

Comment: @MuhammadAli I removed app.cors from the server.js, and reuploaded it to heroku. It's still saying `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://project-api.herokuapp.com/login' from origin 'https://project-front.herokuapp.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'https://project-api.herokuapp.com/' that is not equal to the supplied origin.`